# Is it possible to localize the Mac Welcome Assistant Language to be non English?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, internationalization

I bought new but used Macbook Pro for my mother, and she doesn’t speak English.

But „welcome assistant” screen (which shows first time you open new Mac) is in English. It leads you through region, language, account options, etc.

But when I pick my region and language the assistant itself language still appears in English.

It’s first Macbook in my mothers life. So I would like her to have nice first experience with it. So I want „Welcome assistant” guide her through each step in her native language.

So I want the first thing she will see would be big banner with word „BENVENUTO” instead „WELCOME”.

Can I somehow Pre-select. Localization and then get the new account setup to run in a non-default language?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution.

it looks like there was some problem with preinstalled system.
I just pass through whole assistant in english. And after choosing desired language, the system still was launched still in English. So I ser the desired language in System Preferences, and removed English language.

Then I launched again with Command-R, and reinstalled system.
Now „Welcome assistant” on the begining has language to choose and imidiately changes it to desired language. Perfect.

By the way, sorry for my English ;)